# Creating a SQL function from java causes Exception

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to create a Database using JDBC from Java.

The DB and Table creation goes easily, however now I need to create functions and later a trigger and I keep hitting the wall of exceptions with this function as example:

```
USE ratercases;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `IMC`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `IMC` (altura INT,peso INT)
  RETURNS DOUBLE
BEGIN
  DECLARE AltM DOUBLE;
  DECLARE AltSqr DOUBLE;
  SET AltM=(altura/100);
  SET AltSqr=AltM*AltM;
  RETURN peso/AltSqr;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

If i run the script above on MySQL Workbench there are no problems; However runnning it from Java gets me SQL Syntax Error Exceptions.

I use the following Java code:

```
// ps is a SQL Statement; ratercases is the target Database;
ps.execute("USE ratercases;"
                + "DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `IMC`;"
                + " DELIMITER $$"
                + " CREATE FUNCTION `IMC` (altura INT,peso INT)"
                + " RETURNS DOUBLE"
                + " BEGIN"
                + " DECLARE AltM DOUBLE;"
                + " DECLARE AltSqr DOUBLE;"
                + " SET AltM=(altura/100);"
                + " SET AltSqr=AltM*AltM;"
                + " RETURN peso/AltSqr;"
                + " END $$"
                + " DELIMITER ;");
//
```

Java/SQL is apparently having problems with the Delimiter $$ ...

Can anyone enlighten me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative approach would be to connect to the *ratercases* database directly by specifying it in the connection URL and then execute two separate statements for `DROP` and `CREATE`, avoiding the requirement to use `DELIMITER` at all:

```
ps.execute("DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `IMC`");

ps.execute("CREATE FUNCTION `IMC` (altura INT,peso INT)"
           + " RETURNS DOUBLE"
           + " BEGIN"
           + " DECLARE AltM DOUBLE;"
           + " DECLARE AltSqr DOUBLE;"
           + " SET AltM=(altura/100);"
           + " SET AltSqr=AltM*AltM;"
           + " RETURN peso/AltSqr;");
```